# Why is there no advantage of rolling a die first in chance games?

Tags: probability, dice

[image]
[image]
Let's say if you roll 6, you win. The first player has a chance of winning 1/6. And then, the second player has a chance of winning (5/6)*(1/6) where 5/6 comes from the first player not rolling 6 in his turn, or so I thought. But they say that the second player has an equal chance of winning, 1/6. Why is it?

Comment: I would read _very, very carefully_ what exactly _they_ say.

Comment: @gnasher729 I added the picture. Could you take a look at that?

Comment: The picture is incomplete and particularly unhelpful. Please explain the exact rules of the game.

Comment: @RobArthan "You take turns rolling your dice. In order to win the round, you or your opponent must roll a 3-3, 5-5, 6-6 or a 6-5. You will lose the round if you or your opponent roll a 1-1, 2-2, 4-4 or a 2-1."

Comment: Please put that necessary information in the question and not just in a comment. And clarify what happens if none of the conditions you state are satisfied.

Comment: @RobArthan sorry, I edited it.

Comment: The probabilities of winning and losing are the same so there is no advantage, unless you know how to game the die.

Comment: @Dole So you are saying, when the combinations come out as neither winning pairs or losing pairs making the game continue on, and as a result, the winning chance of someone might change, but even if that's the case, the chance of losing will change as much as the winning chance does, there's no advantage in taking the first turn?

Comment: @user800956 On each round there is equal chance that you win or the opponent wins. Hence it does not matter who throws first. It does not even matter who throws. Of course, unless you know how to game a die.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fairness to you, assuming that the picture with the paragraph describing
the rules is a screenshot from the problem as it was posed to you,
that description of the rules is appallingly bad.

"You will lose the round if you or your opponent roll a 1-1, 2-2, 4-4 or a 2-1."
No, according to everyone else, if your opponent rolls 1-1, 2-2, 4-4, or 2-1,
your *opponent* loses and you *win.*

(Actually, none of the online sources I checked had a simple, ironclad description of the rules; everyone used some ambiguous language. But the description in the problem statement still stands out as the worst I found. The online Encyclopedia Britannica was the best.)

Assuming that there is no way to distinguish 6-5 from 5-6, when you roll there is a
$\frac{5}{36}$ chance that you win immediately because you roll one of the winning rolls,
a $\frac{5}{36}$ chance that you lose immediately because you roll one of the losing rolls,
and a $\frac{26}{36}$ chance that the game simply continues.

When your opponent rolls, there is a
$\frac{5}{36}$ chance that you win immediately because your opponent rolls one of the losing rolls,
a $\frac{5}{36}$ chance that you lose immediately because your opponent rolls one of the winning rolls,
and a $\frac{26}{36}$ chance that the game simply continues.

So it really does not matter who rolls when: every time the dice are rolled, you have the same chance to win or to lose.

How you would know this from the atrociously written problem statement is another question.
Did you pay tuition for this kind of treatment? If so, perhaps you deserve at least a partial refund.

Answer (score 1):

You changed the winning rule to "$6$ wins". If the first $6$ wins then you should go first.

But if the rule is "$6$ wins and $1$ loses" then the game is like the one in the picture. You win or lose with the same probability ($1/6$) on each roll so it does not matter if you go first or second.

Comment: But still, shouldn't the second player have a chance of winning that is 1/6( from the first player losing ) + whatever the chances of their own winning probability, meaning the second has a winning chance more of 1/6 then?

Comment: My point is that, when they say the first person's winning chance is only 1/6, why don't they include the first person winning the game when the first person rolls neither 6 nor 1, and the second person rolls also neither 6 nor 1, and then finally the first person rolls 6?

Comment: @user800956 The second player can also lose immediately if the first player wins. 1/6 chance P1 wins (and P2 loses) on the first roll and a 1/6 chance P1 loses (and P2 wins) on the first roll. Same thing when P2 rolls